# Why is FillContainsWithDetail returning FullyContains?

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

I have the following XAML:

```
<Grid>
    <Rectangle x:Name="RedRect" Fill="Red" Width="100" Height="100" Margin="362,245,316,216"></Rectangle>
    <Rectangle x:Name="GreenRect" Fill="Green" Width="200" Height="200" Margin="118,46,460,315"></Rectangle>
    <Button Content="Button" Height="23" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="10,10,0,0" Name="button1" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="75" Click="button1_Click" />
</Grid>
```

and the following code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   IntersectionDetail res = GreenRect.RenderedGeometry.FillContainsWithDetail(RedRect.RenderedGeometry, .000001, ToleranceType.Relative);
   Debug.WriteLine(res);
}
```

The result is IntersectionDetail.FullyContains, which means that the GreenRect is fully contained within the RedRect (as I understand it). But the rendered view shows otherwise: 
[image: Rendered View]

Why is that?